# Wp rocket plugin makes database too big

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I noticed now the wp rocket plugin makes my database too big. My database is now 5 GB!!!
And in the (wp-options) created 1 million rows, all of them start with  (rocket-...).
I contacted the plugin support team, and they told me:
disable WP Cron, open the wp-config.php file in your main WordPress folder and add the following line before the "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */" line:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Then: Add a Cron job entry through your web hosting control panel. You can set the job to run every 5 or 10 minutes.
Please remember to replace yourdomain.com with your actual domain:

```
wget -q -O - http://yourdomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1
```

......

After I doing all of this job, any thing not change, and my DB is still 5 GB.

And the support team doesn't answer my questions.

If there is any one knows what I have to do, Please help me...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's a good question, but you should ask it on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com. There are many more wordpress specialists there to help you with this sort of problem

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this. You are perfect 

Comment: @hoseinshekofteh check the Database tab in WP Rocket's settings. You *might* be able to clean some things up there.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is not there. I cleaned database cache with wp rocket plugin many times, and nothing changes.

Comment: @boisvert This question is probably off topic on wordpress.stackexchange.com too - please note that "*questions concerning third party plugins and themes*" are off topic on that site.

Comment: hosein, this is something that required indepth knowledge of a third-party plugin, so  you are unlikely to get the expertise you need here. Have you tried the support forum for the plugin to get help from other users of the plugin?